# Error in graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')

Tags: machine-learning, graphlab, sframe

I am doing **Machine Learning** Course from Coursera **by University of Washington**. In which I am using iPython's graphlab. During practise when I execute below command:

```
sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
```

I am getting the error:

```
InvalidProductKey                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c5971b60b216> in <module>()
----> 1 sales=graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in __init__(self, data, format, _proxy)
865             self.__proxy__ = _proxy
866         else:
--> 867             self.__proxy__ = UnitySFrameProxy(glconnect.get_client())
868             _format = None
869             if (format == 'auto'):

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/main.pyc in get_client()
138     """
139     if not is_connected():
--> 140         launch()
141     assert is_connected(), ENGINE_START_ERROR_MESSAGE
142     return __CLIENT__

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/main.pyc in launch(server_addr, server_bin, server_log, auth_token, server_public_key)
 90         if server:
 91             server.try_stop()
 ---> 92         raise e
 93     server.set_log_progress(True)
 94     # start the client

 InvalidProductKey: Product key not found.
```

(Note the ipython notebook and home_data.gl are in same folder.)

Comment: 'Product key' sounds like you need a license key for Graphlab.

Comment: how can i get this licence ? how much is that

Comment: @Lok how did you get it to work?

Comment: I got the license from the Coursera, as I was doing the University of Washington course.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the product key for graphlab using the command 
graphlab.product_key.set_product_key('PRODUCT KEY HERE')